# Обращение к значению внутри ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, css, ссылки, теги

Есть код

```css
    .menu {
      position: relative;
      width: 370px;
    }

    .menu ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .menu li {
      padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.3em;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    ul.level1 {
      border: 1px solid thistle;
    }

    ul.level1>li {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-bottom: 1px solid thistle;
    }

    ul.level1>li:last-child {
      border-bottom: none;
    }

    ul.level2 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
      max-width: 559px;
      max-height: 1010px;
      padding: 0.5em 0.3em 0.5em 0.3em;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid thistle;
      visibility: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      column-count: 2;
    }

    ul.level2>li {
      padding: 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }

    ul.level2>ul>li {
      padding: 0;
    }

    ul.level2>li>ul>li {
      padding: 0;
    }

    ul.level1>li:hover ul.level2 {
      visibility: visible;
    }

    .menu a {
      color: #333;
    }

    .alignblock {
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .submenu__title {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .submenu__title a {
      display: block;
      color: black;
      font: 13px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial, sans-serif;
      /* line-height: 1.5; */
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 3px 5px;
    }

    .submenu__item {
      /* margin-bottom: 0px; */
    }

    .submenu__item a {
      display: block;
      color: gray;
      font: 13px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial, sans-serif;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 3px 5px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="mainwrap">
      <div class="mainmenu">
        <span>
                    <span>
                        <button data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#menu" class="hamburger animated fadeInLeft noclose is-open" type="button">
                        <span class="hamb-top"></span>
        <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
        <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
        <span><div class="label menu-label" id="myelement">КАТАЛОГ ТОВАРОВ</div></span>
        </span>

        <nav class="menu">
          <ul class="level1">
            <li id="l1">
              <div class="alignblock">Бытовая техника для кухни</div>
              <ul class="level2">
                <li class="submenu">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="submenu__title">
                      <a href="#">Крупная бытовая техника</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Холодильники</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Морозильные камеры</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Морозильные лари</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Плиты газовые </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                  <ul>
                    <li class="submenu__title">
                      <a href="#">New title</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Холодильники</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Морозильные камеры</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Морозильные лари</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Плиты газовые </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="l2">
              <div class="alignblock">Item 2</div>
            </li>
            <li id="l3">
              <div class="alignblock">Item 3 +</div>
              <ul class="level2">
                <li>Sub-Item 3-1</li>
                <li>Sub-Item 3-2</li>
                <li>Sub-Item 3-3</li>
                <li>Sub-Item 3-4</li>
                <li>Sub-Item 3-5</li>
                <li>Sub-Item 3-6</li>
                <li>Sub-Item 3-7</li>
                <li>Sub-Item 4-8</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="l2">
              <div class="alignblock">Item 4</div>
            </li>
            <li id="l2">
              <div class="alignblock">Item 5</div>
            </li>
            <li id="l2">
              <div class="alignblock">Item 6</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Требуется записывать в переменные (начинающиеся со слова `value`) тексты пунктов меню, на которых был произведен клик или  был наведен курсор мыши

```js
let valuemenuitem = '';
let valuecategoryitem = '';
let valuesubcategoryitem = '';
let clicklink = document.querySelectorAll('.nestedblock');
let categoryitemlink = document.querySelectorAll('.submenu_title > a');
let subcategoryitemlink = document.querySelectorAll('.submenu_item > a');
for (let j = 0; j < clicklink.length; j++) {
  clicklink[j].addEventListener('hover', function(e) {
    valuemenuitem = /*значение внутри <a href="" class="nestedblock"></a> */
  }, true);
  clicklink[j].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    valuemenuitem = /*значение внутри <a href="" class="nestedblock"></a> */
  }, true);
}


/* let categoryitemlink =  document.querySelectorAll('ul.level1>li:hover>ul.level2>li>ul>li'); */


for (let k = 0; k < categoryitemlink.length; k++) {
  categoryitemlink[k].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    valuecategoryitem = /*значение внутри <li class="submenu_title"><a href="">...</a></li>*/
  }, true);
}



for (let l = 0; l < categoryitemlink.length; l++) {
  subcategoryitemlink[l].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    valuesubcategoryitem = /*значение внутри <li class="submenu_item"><a href="">...</a></li>*/
  }, true);
}
```

Каким образом можно получить значения внутри ссылок  - `значение внутри <a href="" class="nestedblock">...</a>`, `значение внутри <li class="submenu_title"><a href="">...</a></li>` и `значение внутри <li class="submenu_item"><a href="">...</a></li>`?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, ток так:

```js
let subcategoryitemlink = document.querySelectorAll('.submenu__item a');

for (let l = 0; l < subcategoryitemlink.length; l++) {
  subcategoryitemlink[l].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let valuesubcategoryitem = this.innerText;
  }, true);
}
```